# Can I create a lambda function in CloudFormation that runs an aws cli command that updates nameservers for the registered domain?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I registered a domain example.com in my Route53, now I created a CloudFormation stack that creates a hosted zone called example53 an A record example.com that routes traffic to my ALB and an ACM resources that should validate the example.com domain.

The problem is it will never validate the domain if the nameservers are wrong and before the ACM resource I need to update the nameservers for the domain registered in my Route53 with the name servers the NS record has in my hosted zone.

There is no CloudFormation domain resource manipulation but there is an AWS CLI command that can change the name servers for the domain, is there a way I can run that AWS CLI command with a Lambda resource created in CloudFormation?

I run the stack with a Makefile, can a Makefile run the AWS CLI command and realized the conditions such as when HostedZone is first created.

Comment: Can you clarify, CFN supports autovalidation of ACM certs for domains from R53. Why do you wan to use AWS CLI for that?

Comment: Becasue that auto validation doesn't work for me, it creates the CNAME in my hostedzone but it never validates the SSL, how can it if the domain servers for the domain don't have the nameservers that the hosted zone NS record has?

Comment: So then you have to use `custom resource` in your CFN to automate all this.

Comment: In what way must I use that, what will the custom resource do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) on CloudFormation. The resource would be in the form of a **lambda function**. The function would use AWS SDK, e.g. `boto3` to perform actions on R53 resources that you require.

Since the function is *developed by you*, not provided by AWS, the custom resource can do whatever you want it to do. Its not limited by regular CloudFormation shortcomings.

Comment: Can you hel me with the beggining of the Code: ZipFile: part? Can I !Sub in the ZipFile? I need to !Sub HostedZone.NameServers.

Comment: @KatranPlague You can make new question and provide all relevant code snippets for it. Comments are not a place for asking totally new questions.